# Normalizer of a Sylow subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

In this question [Sylow subgroups of soluble groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714780/sylow-subgroups-of-soluble-groups) Jack Schmidt mentions that the normalizer of $P$ in $S_p$ is solvable. Suppose $P$ is generated by a cycle of length $p$. Could you provide any hints, why is it true, because I do not quite see the solvability of the normalizer and why actually $G$ (which is transitive) lies in it.

Comment: First prove $C_{S_p}(P)=P$. Then $N_{S_p}(G)/C_{S_p}(G)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm Aut}(P)$, which is cyclic of order $p-1$, so $N_{S_p}(G)$ is solvable. (In fact $N_{S_p}(G)$ has order $p(p-1)$ and is $2$-transitive.) What exactly is $G$ here?

Comment: @DerekHolt as stated in a quoted question, $G \leq S_p$ for prime $p$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: $G$ is a transitive subgroup of $S_p$ with a normal Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Comment: Well if $P$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, then $G$ is in the normalizer of $P$.

Answer (score 2):

By counting the number of elements of order $p$ in $S_p$ and by using the fact that elements of order $p$ are conjugate in $S_p$, you can prove that $|C_{S_p}(P)| = p$ and $|N_{S_p}(P)| = p(p-1)$.

Then prove that $N_{S_p}(P) / C_{S_p}(P)$ is cyclic of order $p-1$, so $N_{S_p}(P)$ is solvable.

The second part of your question is answered by Jack in the other question, but here it is again with more detail:

Let $G \leq S_p$ be solvable and transitive. Then $G$ is primitive, since any stabilizer has prime index $p$ (so every stabilizer is maximal). Hence any nontrivial normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ is transitive, since the orbits under $N$ form a block system.

Take $N \neq 1$ to be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. Now $N$ is transitive, so $p$ divides the order of $N$. On the other hand $G$ is solvable, so $N$ is elementary abelian of prime power order. Thus $N = P$ and $P$ is a normal subgroup.